# GWT - How to have multiple cell types on the same level and in the same children list?

Tags: gwt

I would like to have multiple cell types on the same tree level and in the same children list.
This is the structure I would like to create

```
A (Foo)
- AA (Bar)
- AB (Baz)
- AA (Baz)
```

This post says that the above structure cannot be created. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/xUEf50-r2Lo

Here is the part that we are intrested in :

> The following is supported.  The children of A and B are different
>   types (Bar and Baz) but are both one level deep:
>
> ```
>     A (Foo)
>     - AA (Bar)
>     - AB (Bar)
>     - AA (Bar)
>     B (Foo)
>     - BA (Baz)
>     - BB (Baz)
>     - BC (Baz)
> ```
>
> The following is not supported.  The children of A cannot be of
>   multiple types.
>
> ```
> A (Foo)
> - AA (Bar)
> - AB (Baz)
> - AA (Biz)
> ```

### The previous post is from 2010, and I'm wondering if nowadays is this structure still unsupported?

If we can achieve it, some ideas or samples would be great. 
I tried using a base cell class for Bar and Baz....but that was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I created a custom cell that has to 2 different UIRenderers. Depending on a flag from the DTO we can decide what renderer to use. Each cell type is defined in it's on xml.

```
public class DualFaceCell extends AbstractCell<DTO> {

@UiTemplate("SimpleFaceCell.ui.xml")
interface SimpleFaceRenderer extends UiRenderer {
    void render(SafeHtmlBuilder sb);

    void onBrowserEvent(SimpleFaceCell o, NativeEvent e, Element p);
}

@UiTemplate("ComplexFaceCell.ui.xml")
interface ComplexFaceRenderer extends UiRenderer {
    void render(SafeHtmlBuilder sb, String name);

    void onBrowserEvent(ComplexFaceCell o, NativeEvent e, Element p);
}

private final SimpleFaceRenderer simpleRenderer = GWT.create(SimpleFaceRenderer .class);
private final ComplexFaceRenderer complexRenderer = GWT.create(ComplexFaceRenderer .class);

public DualFaceCell() {
    super(BrowserEvents.CLICK);
} 

    @Override
public void render(Context context, DTO value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (value.isSimpleFaceCell()) {
        simpleRenderer.render(sb);
    } else {
        complexRenderer.render(sb, value.getName());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, UIHandler is not usable anymore. Even if I have declared in the xml and ui:field = "add" if we want to handle it's action with annotation like :

```
@UiHandler({ "add" })
void onAddClicked(ClickEvent event, Element parent) {
    Window.alert("Add clicked");
}
```

The following error is displayed :

```
"add" is not a known field name as listed in the @UiHandler annotation in "void onAddListClicked(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent event, com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element parent)" of com.bla.bla.client.view.DualFaceCell
```

### Do you have any idea how to trick the UIHandler to work properly?